# AJAX and setInterval for window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval, window.location

```
//Gather AJAX links
var ajaxLink = $("#logo, .navLink, .tableLink, .footerLink");

//Mark the recent state as null (because there is none yet)
var recentState = null;

//Initialize the page state based on the URL (bookmarking compatibility)
window.onload = function() {
    //If no page state exists, assume the user is at index.html
    if (window.location.hash == "") {
        window.location.hash = "page=index";
    }

    //Load the page state based on the URL
    loadStateFromURL();

    //Keep the page state synchronized (back/forward button compatibility)
    setInterval(loadStateFromURL, 500);

    //Exit
    return;
}

//Use AJAX for certain links
ajaxLink.click(function() {
    //Update the URL
    window.location.hash = "page=" + $(this).attr("id");

    //Load the page state based on the URL
    loadStateFromURL();

    //Return false or else page will refresh
    return false;
});

//Load the page state based on the URL
function loadStateFromURL() {
    //If nothing has changed, exit
    if (window.location.hash == recentState) {
        return;
    }

    //Mark the recent state
    recentState = window.location.hash;

    //Go through an array of all AJAX links and check their IDs
    for (var i = 0; i < ajaxLink.length; i++) {
        //If we find a link's ID that matches the current state, load the relevant content
        if ("#page=" + ajaxLink[i].id == window.location.hash) {
            //Load contents into article.main
            $("article.main").fadeOut(0).load(ajaxLink[i].href, function(response, status, xhr) {
                //Show an error if the request fails
                if (status == "error") {
                    $("article.main").load("./404.html");
                    window.location.hash = "page=404";
                }
            }).fadeIn(500);

            //Update the page title
            document.title = "\u2622 My Website Name \u2622 " + ajaxLink[i].text;
            document.getElementById("headH2").textContent = ajaxLink[i].text;

            //State has been fixed, exit
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works flawlessly when I run it locally!!!

But when I throw it on the web server my AJAX'd links will refresh the page when I first visit. However, if I use the back button then try the link again (or I'm assuming if the page is already in the browser cache), it will work properly.

I cannot allow this, because when people first visit my page the first link they click on will not operate as intended.

One of things I've also been testing is I'll bookmark my own site with a breadcrumb bookmark (example.com/#page=14) and see if it updates without my page already being in the browser cache. Again, it works on my local machine but not on my web server.

Answer (score 0):

use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
ajaxLink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Update the URL
    window.location.hash = "page=" + $(this).attr("id");

    //Load the page state based on the URL
    loadStateFromURL();

    //Return false or else page will refresh
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Still nothing, however I read through the .preventDefault documentation and I'm baffled why .preventDefault isn't working, it totally should!

Comment: have you tried using `return false` instead of `return` inside the `loadStateFromURL()` function?

Comment: I appreciate you helping me. I alternated `return false` in each `return` then tried it in both `return`, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue maybe is that when you are applying your click event to these links, they may not be loaded to the DOM. So the possible solution is to put `ajaxLink.click(function() { ... });` part inside `window.load` event or `document.ready` event. Since you have used window.load event, you can do something like this.

```
//Initialize the page state based on the URL (bookmarking compatibility)
window.onload = function() {
    //If no page state exists, assume the user is at index.html
    if (window.location.hash == "") {
        window.location.hash = "page=index";
    }

    //Load the page state based on the URL
    loadStateFromURL();

    //Keep the page state synchronized (back/forward button compatibility)
    setInterval(loadStateFromURL, 500);

    //Use AJAX for certain links
    ajaxLink.click(function() {
        //Update the URL
        window.location.hash = "page=" + $(this).attr("id");

        //Load the page state based on the URL
        loadStateFromURL();

        //Return false or else page will refresh
        return false;
    });

    //Exit
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me thinking about behavior while the DOM loading, which eventually led me toward the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question, had to continuously parse the AJAX links to stay updated with the DOM as it changes.

First I put the ajaxLink declaration into a function:

```
//Gather AJAX links
function parseAjaxLinks() {
    var ajaxLink = $("#logo, .navLink, .tableLink, .footerLink");
    return ajaxLink;
}
```

Then I had to put the ajaxLink click events into a function:

```
//Load the page state from an AJAX link click event
function loadStateFromClick() {
    //Update the AJAX links
    var ajaxLink = parseAjaxLinks();

    ajaxLink.click(function() {
        //Update the URL
        window.location.hash = "page=" + $(this).attr("id");

        //Load the page state based on the URL
        loadStateFromURL();

        //Return false or else page will refresh
        return false;
    });
}
```

Then I added a line in my window.onload event to keep my AJAX click events synchronized with the DOM (this adds overhead, but oh well):

```
//Initialize the page state based on the URL (bookmarking compatibility)
window.onload = function() {
    //If no page state exists, assume the user is at index.html
    if (window.location.hash == "") {
        window.location.hash = "page=index";
        recentState = window.location.hash;
    }

    //Load the page state based on the URL
    loadStateFromURL();

    //Keep the page state synchronized (back/forward button compatibility)
    setInterval(loadStateFromURL, 250);

    //Keep AJAX links synchronized (with DOM)
    setInterval(loadStateFromClick, 250);

    //Exit
    return;
}
```

If you have a keen eye, you saw I had called the new parseAjaxLinks in my new loadStateFromClick function, so I added a line to the top of my loadStateFromURL function to keep the links updated in there as well:

```
//Load the page state based on the URL
function loadStateFromURL() {
    //Update the AJAX links
    var ajaxLink = parseAjaxLinks();

...
```

What I learned from this is the variables which are dependent on the DOM need to be continuously updated. While the DOM is loading, things are unpredictable and kind of sucks. ****Drinks beer****